# Admin control panel using PHP/MySQL

Tags: php, html, mysql

I was looking for a code for a web page which has the functionality wherein some previously registered admins can login and after doing so, they can add, modify or delete data from a product list already available in a database.

Comment: This is beyond the scope of a simple Q&A question. Stack Overflow is for helping you with specific programming problems, not for getting developers to write code for you.

Comment: phpmyadmin with proper permissions?

Comment: tried phpmyadmin, but i really couldn't figure out how to migrate the database. must be a silly doubt, but well, it is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a very open ended question and there are literally 100s of ways to go about it. You essentially need two systems

- Login/registration ( that allows registration of new admins and allows them to login later)

Example: http://net.tutsplus.com/articles/news/how-to-build-a-login-system-for-a-simple-website/?search_index=6

- and then CRUD part

The system that allows to Create, Update, Insert or Delete stuff from the database.

One example of that would be 
http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/real-world-oop-with-php-and-mysql

Again, it might not be the best or the easiest way. But definitely a place to start.